# Jenkins and selenium

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I have Jenkins service running in docker container in private docker network. 
I have selenium hub and chrome and Firefox also running in container under same network as jenkins..chrome and Firefox are linked to hub.
but Jenkins can't connect to hub, should I linked them too? 
and it there a way to link RUNNING containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix is : I had to write docker-compose.yml file and linked hub and jenkins container also have under same network